# Can you help translate this Chinese scroll?

Tags: translation

Can you please translate this Chinese scroll for me?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdilC.jpg)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

生意興隆 - (A wish) for booming businesses

These are called "Fai Chun":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fai_chun

Comment: Thank you. So it's essentially a talisman? Also, it seems the written scroll text and the printed one vary quite a bit. How do you find the printed equivalent when it looks very different to the handwritten text?

Comment: I wouldn't say talisman (where it's more leading towards 'protection spell' sort of meaning).  It's more a decoration that usually consist of 4 words for good luck / prosperity / etc, and very commonly used during chinese new year.  As for why I find the print version, I kinda see these every years and i'm over 30 lol so I can eyeball it from the get go

Comment: When you google the third word, there's plenty results that gives you the different writing of the same word:

https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=kVEKXZH8K8jl_Qab8JG4BA&q=%E8%88%88%E5%AD%97&oq=%E8%88%88%E5%AD%97&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8.1106.1106..1680...0.0..0.99.99.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.xJn24IB6_KA